# Understanding command update-os

Tags: linux, command

I'm new to linux based devices...

I have that device which firmware need to be updated using command update-os

When i type this command it gives me a hint on how to use it...

`Update-os [--dry-run] FILE | URL [-V ]`

What does all this mean? Please note that i have two files for update ... One is called os-update and the other is update.bin file...

How to use this command? I tried to run the following command in the same directory containing the .bin file

`Update-os update.bin`

But it prompted me again with the usage of the command. Then I tried:

`Update-os update.bin | /home/test/`

But it says `/home/test/ permission denied`

I tried with sudo...

`Sudo Update-os update.bin | /home/test/`

But I get the same permission denied...

Any help will be appreciated... Regards,

Comment: Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: I think you're much more likely to get an answer if you tell us what this device is and how you knew "update-os" was the right command to begin with.

Comment: Note that the distinction between upper- and lowercase is significant on Linux, so the command is "Update-os", not "update-os".  Maybe some more typos?

Comment: Please edit you question: correct case of words. Show (don't describe) what happened.Tell us what `update-os` is. Tell us what `update.bin` is. Tell us what is in `/home/test/` and what you expect of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to read usage:

```
Update-os [--dry-run] FILE | URL [-V ]
```

The first word is the executable you are trying to run: `Update-os`.

`[--dry-run]` - The square brackets means "optional parameter", so you can add this option or not - your choice. Usually the 'dry-run' means the executable will tell you what it supposed to do during the run without actually doing it. Recommend to use it for a first few runs, until you sure that it will do exactly what you expect it to do.

`FILE | URL` - the bar `|` symbol here means "or". You can specify either file or url in command line. The executable will use that file or url to do the work.
Please note: using `|` in command line has a different meaning - it would be a piping `stdout` of one command into `stdin` of another. And when you do `Uodate-os update.bin | /home/test/` that means you want all what is printed by `Update-os` on the screen to be processed by a command `/home/test/` but since that is a directory and not a command - you getting an error.

`[-V ]` is again optional. Not exactly clear what it will do, but usually, `-v` or `-V` option tells the executable, to print its version or be verbose during the work. You would have to find that yourself, in documentation on the executable. Or just by running it (with `--dry-run` preferably).

Answer (score -1):

The title of the question is "Understanding a linux command".

So I guess anything else even your example is tangential.

I teach unix command from bottom up, completely differently than schools and how it is normally taught, and in my experience this works much better on my students, than traditional approaches.

---

So here we go:

The first thing you need to understand is distinction between a `program` and a `process`.

Distinction on unix is very simple: `program` is just a dumb "dead" file on the disk (filesystem) containing some code, that can be run (but it is not in the state of running). `program` is important, but is also quite useless in itself: it is like a skeleton of a long dead animal.

Living animals do need skeletons to live too, but extracted from them, skeleton itself is just a dead matter. Same way a `program` is such a dead matter. Programs pile on disks (like dead bodies), and these programs are basically just files and they exist in storage only.

Now a `process` is "living" instance of any program in a computer memory.

I.e. when you run a program on unix, system takes it's file (a skeleton), constructs a `process` in memory somewhere (a "living animal") and puts that skeleton (the program) INTO THE ANIMAL (the process). Process is "more" than a `program`, but it cannot live without a `program` inside itself (has a program in it's tummy).

So at the end of the "run program" command you get running, ergo "living", `process` which has "shape" and "behaves" according to its skeleton (a `program`) that was put into it. Processes "exist" in memory and live on the CPUs.

Now important question is, for example, how many process can spawn from a single program?

And the answer is many (actually infinite number, or rather how many will fit in your memory).

There is actually 1:N mapping between the program and processes running it.

With this information you probably already understand more then the other beginners.

---

Now, as we saw, process is much more, than a program that it is running.

Process has CPU assigned to it.
Process has memory assigned to it, and many other computer resources too.

One other thing that process has also assigned to it, is called an `argument vector`.

What it is ?

It is an "ordered bag of words". Ordered means that order of the words in the bag matters. If you know programming, you can imagine it as an array.

---

Why do we need it?

Let us return back to the moment, when system is creating a process: system, at minimum, certainly needs to know a name of a program, from which to construct that new process.

The name of the program to use to construct the process, is always first word of an `argument vector`.

This works quite well for many simple programs, but purpose of some programs is much more complex: like to process something, transform it from something  to something else, to do something wit it, and perhaps return some results.

And besides naming a program file to use, this is exactly what an `argument vector` is used for: it is used to pass any arbitrary information to the spawning process, needed for it to perform it's task.

---

There are no limitation on number of words in an `argument vector`, other then they have to be distinct. These words (in `argument vector`) are passed to the process as is. By now it would be a little bit silly to call each such element of an `argument vector` array simply "a word". To distinguish them from "normal" "text" words, we call then nicer: `arguments`.

Meaning of the arguments, and their order, is understood only by the program being "processized", ie turend into the process. So each and every program is it's own universe, own language, of its own words/arguments, that it understands.

Resulting process then reads the words from the `argument vector` one by one and starts it's work based on their contents - this, again, is controlled by the program.

It is customary, that standalone word/argument in an `arg. vector` means a file, or a path to a file (or a directory).

---

Shell automatically splits input line into words of a vector on a space character boundary: ie. `mv oldfile newfile` shell line will end up chopped into `argument vector` of `["mv","oldfile","newfile"]`.

Now, as we said, the system always interprets a very first word of an `argument vector` as path to a program which to "processize" - instantiate.
So in this exemplar case the program to be run would be `mv`.

So using all the information we have so far, vector of `["mv","oldfile","newfile"]` translates roughly to: run a program named `mv` and give it two arguments `oldfile` and `newfile`.

Now, what each argument means, is, as we already said, interpreted completely by `mv` program itself.

So in the case of `mv` its program usually **moves** files with same names as arguments passed to it (besides last argument) into the file (if it does not exist already), or a directory (if it exists already), used as a last word of passed-in `argument vector`.

Thus `["mv","oldfile","newfile"]` basically ends up meaning either "move" (or rather "rename") file named "oldfile" into file named "newfile", or "move" file named "oldfile" into directory named "newfile", if it exists.

And repeating again, what resulting process does with the arguments, depends entirely on the program being invoked (i.e. on `mv` program).

---

We already said, it is often customary (but not necessary!!!), that each standalone word in an `arg. vector` means a path.

But sometimes we want to pass other information to the program, not just paths, like, for example, change its behaviour slightly.

After decades of use, an informal consensus formed, that arguments beginning with `-` or `--` characters, are the ones modifying the process behaviours.

We call each such argument `a flag`. And once again meanings of flags are completely program dependent!!!

---

So for example program `mv` also accepts an argument, a flag, named `-v`, and also a flag named `--verbose`, both of which make it do same thing: print out information about what it is doing.

Thus `mv -v oldfile newfile` will end up being chopped into `argument vector` of `["mv","-v","oldfile","newfile"]` and resulting `mv` process will print out:

```
$ mv -v oldfile newfile
renamed 'oldfile' -> 'newfile'
```

And rename 'oldfile' to 'newfile'.

---

Some programs are complex enough, that they need to have at least one argument provided, to do any useful work.

That is the case of your program.

So, when invoked without any arguments, instead of doing nothing, programs like these tend to at least print out a little hint, describing how the program can be used.

After some decades of use a little "mini language" evolved around these hints.

BE WARNED THOUGH!!!

This little hint language has nothing to do with shell language, as you already discovered.

If anything hint line is invalid shell line at best, at worst, when fed back into the shell as-is, it will do something completely wrong, potentially leading into catastrophic damage.

SO NEVER EVER FEED HINT LINE BACK IN TO THE SHELL AS-IS, AS YOU DID!!!

`[` character in hint line has completely different meaning than `[` character in shell line. Never confuse the two!

Similarly `|` means something completely else on hint line, than on shell line! Again do not confuse the two!

---

As White Owl@ already said, by tradition any argument within `[]` brackets means that that argument is optional.

`|` in hint line means `or` or rather choice between multiple possible invocations.

Arguments typed in `BIG LETTERS` like `FILE` or `URL`, mean that the argument/word will be interpreted as given "class" of "object": ie the word will be understood either as path, or as URL to the internet server.

How the program determines which is which, depends, again, completely on the program itself, but for example, usually, if "file" argument begins with url schema characters (i.e. "https://") the program assumes it is an URL.

---

As you already noticed by now, probably, reading (and writing(!)) hint lines is kind of an art (a dark art even). Frankly nobody knows what your program will really do. Hint line is exactly that: a hint.

Only way to know for sure, is to read a given program documentation.

That is sole authoritative source explaining how the program really works (and even that doesn't always hold - for example there might be error in documentation(!!), or in the program(!!!)).

Yet as you see, we senior users have seen enough of hint lines in our lives, and many programmers have wrote enough of programs in their lives, that we can roughly assume, what this program will do and when.

From it's name and self-reported hint line, we can "guesstimate" this:

- the program will update OS of a device: `update-os` (be careful: unices are case sensitive, size of the letter matters!!!)
- the program can, OPTIONALLY, do a test run, pretending to update the device and do everything, as if it was updating a device - without actually performing update for real - this is what `[--dry-run]` usually means
- the program can update device either from local file (`FILE`) or by downloading the update directly from internet (`URL`)
- the program accepts optional flag, called `-V` - what this flag does we don't know, but based on experience:

  - it will either print out program version: as in `-V` = `version`
  - or it will print out more detailed output about its actions: as in `-V` = `verbose` (but traditionally `verbose` is more often under flag `-v` than not)
  - finally, in reality `-V` could easily mean `Voldemort`

In the end, only creator of the program really knows what it will do. And sometimes not even them....

---

I hope, you now understand everything important lurking behind your question, and that you realized your silly mistakes!

Like when you fed your shell with incoherent mumbling crap, that it possibly could not understand, under any circumstances.

You should also be thankful, that the hint line did not contain any "dangerous" shell characters, and did no damage to your computer.